# Storing BST values into an array using index

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a function that uses a BST to store its values in an array. I have a global variable index = -1; dynamically created array with size of BST.

```
int index = -1;
struct treeNode{
    int value;
    treeNode *left;
    treeNode *right;
}

void treeTraversal(treeNode *node, int array[], int index){
    index++;
    if (node != nullptr){
        array[index] = node->value;
        treeTraversal(node->left, array, index);
        treeTraversal(node->right, array, index);
    }
}
```

It works for some trees with structures like this

```
        6
    5
4
```

But it's not working for a structure like this

```
    3
2       4
            5
```

Comment: How did you store the values into the tree structure?

Comment: I didn't it's an assignment and the int main part of the code I didn't create

Comment: I'd recommend to step through your code with a debugger and watch how the `index` parameter changes. Check if that meets your expectations.

Comment: I've been going through the code and testing it with the different test cases but whenever I change something, another test case will work and another will fail

Comment: You are trying to write code by trial and error; this approach works, but it is extremely slow. You must *understand* what these lines of code do, before you can hope to get them working properly. Also, the code you posted does not work for the first tree. **I strongly advise you to go back and master simpler exercises before you attempt this one.** I suggest writing code that can copy an array, then code that can traverse a tree printing values but not storing them, then traversing and printing with a counter, *then* this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The array assignment should be in the middle of tree traversal

```
int index = 0;
struct treeNode{
int value;
treeNode *left;
treeNode *right;
}

void treeTraversal(treeNode *node, int array[], int *index){
if (node != nullptr){

    treeTraversal(node->left, array, &index);
    array[index++] = node->value;
    treeTraversal(node->right, array, &index);
    }
}
```

[Tree Sort Tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-sort/)

Comment: I've tried that as well it works for some test cases but doesn't work for the second case above

Comment: It's not storing the last element in the second tree structure above

Comment: You need to pass pointer to index. Your declaration should be void treeTraversal(treeNode *node, int array[], int *)

Comment: But my global variable is declared int index = -1; how can I pass that into the parameter?

Comment: ok you need to make 3 changes
a) your global index =0
b)index++ needs to be after the array[index] = node->value, so you can write this line as
array[index++] = node->value;
c) if you pass only index and not pointer to index to the traverse function then index will be reset when you come up from one branch, hence you need to pass pointer to index

Comment: I can't change the global index variable though, I'm doing an assignment and those are the given pre conditions. I'm just creating the function and the assignment tests my function. I ran over the code, based on the second example tree above, and I call the function, it will give me array with 3, 4, 5 but then the index isn't updated, and the second if statement will go through and replace 4 with 2

Comment: you are not allowed to change global index?

Comment: @Zarari then just change `index++` in his code to `++index`

Comment: prog.cpp:70:18: error: invalid types 'int*[int*]' for array subscript
     array[index++] = node->key; I'm getting this error after I tried to change the parameter of the index to a pointer